# How to merge 2 objects

Tags: objects

I am an new blender user. But can someone tell how to get 2 objects together. I want those object in UV mapping on an single file. This model is imported from sketch up and loaded in blender. I Did that becasue texturing is easier in blender I heard.

Thanks for the help already!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select them, then hit CTRL+J. One of them must be active.

Comment: Thanks! it worked!